# .net application memory leak when load html file in HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: .net, windbg

i have a lot of html file need to read and parse by HtmlAgilityPack.when run a application the memory usage always increase immediately and release memory slow.
when i use a windbg tool and check a memory dump,found a **system.bytes[]** used a lot of memory.

the below is my pseudo-code:

**open a file**

```
//read a html file in disk
var stream = OpenFile();//
//de-compress in gzip mode
var de_stream = GZip_Decompress(stream);            
stream.close();
var doc=LoadHtml(de_stream,Encoding.Utf8);
//close a close
de_stream.close();
```

**load a html string**

function LoadHtml(stream,encoding)

```
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
using (var sr = new StreamReader(stream, encoding, false,4096))
{
    var html = sr.ReadToEnd();
    doc.LoadHtml(html);
    sr.Close();
}
```

when my application running and open a hundred of file(file average length is 100K)

```
$dumpheap -stat
```

[image]

```
$dumpheap -mt 56394944 -min 10240
```

[image]
i check a last object in mt 56394944 .

```
!do 3d67a240
```

[image]

the other objects in MT 56394944 also is a html content.when i closed a stream the object in bytes array still hold in memory?

if i change my above code and remove a **LoadHtml** function call,everything is okay,no high memory usage,no object in byte arrays hold in memory.

```
var stream = OpenFile();
var de_stream = GZip_Decompress(stream);            
stream.close();
//var doc=LoadHtml(de_stream,Encoding.Utf8);remove this call
de_stream.close();
```

i need a help some suggestion,release byte array objects when loaded html file.

[edit]
when use a **!gcroot [byte array address]** is no any output.

```
....
Object 0x188b0cb8 contains an invalid object reference 0x1e7538f8.
Scan Thread 25 OSTHread f40
Scan Thread 26 OSTHread 8e8
....    
Scan Thread 30 OSTHread 16e0
Object 0x237115f8 contains an invalid object reference 0x24866df8.
....
```

[edit]

i checkd a GC static.
[image]

Comment: The GC will reclaim memory when it _needs_ to. This is not an indication of a leak, but of the GC working as usual.

Comment: @Oded,thanks for reply.i know the GC will collection those objects when needed.but when a  application running long time and open a hundred of file in a minute in multi-thread,the memory usage always increase,it will reach to maximum memory in system? i updated my question about GC.

Comment: The invalid object reference with gcroot could mean the object has been discarded already. You did a dumpobject (!do) on 3d67a240 which gave you a result. What does !gcroot 3d67a240  do with this object?

Comment: @Oded Having the same issue as op, except the memory usage will eventually hit the system limit and the application will crash from an out of memory exception. I feel the GC is either not doing the trick or HTMLAgility pack has an issue.

Comment: @DouglasGaskell - to be sure you'd need to profile the application. I will say this - the HAP is no longer an active project - may well have a memory leak.